# HDD making clicking noise (video included)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My HDD is making clicking noise. The head isn't stuck half way through the platter
yet YouTube videos related to data recovery in such cases weren't helpful.

Please see recording here https://utcloud.ddns.net/index.php/s/YBaby0MGCmdrosh  password is `harddisk`.

I haven't got a spare one of this type so I can't really replace the circuit board which is what may help.

The HDD is a goner but I still want to try to make it work at least to the point where the disk is detected by a computer and mounts it so I can recover the data.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: The link to your video does not work.  It also not clear what your question is exactly.  What you describe typically should only be handled by a company that specializes in data recovery.

Comment: @Ramhound  Don't know what to say. I checked the link from 3 different devices and 1 device outside of my LAN network and all works.

Comment: @Ramhound I can confirm the link is working.

Comment: Is that video of your own disk, or someone else's disk that has been making a similar noise? If you've removed the cover of your own drive, odds are you will never be able to use it again and will need to get it professionally recovered.

Comment: @SamForbis  I'm aware of that. It's my friend's HDD. He doesn't care about the HDD, he just wants the data. So the HDD is a goner but I still want to try salvage the data. I'm trying to figure out how the make the disk work again so it's detected by computer and mounts it.

Comment: You should never open a HDD in a dusty environment.

Comment: @Tetsujin  I'm OP of that post. Reaching out to a professional service is the last resort. Especially when possibility of recovering the data DIY isn't ruled out.

Comment: Nobody has dealt with this before ??? This can't be a unique problem.

Comment: Sorry, the 'does this answer' is automatically added when someone flags a duplicate. You should have added detail to the original question rather than posted another. If it wasn't dead before you took the cover off, it is now. It needs a professional recovery service. Everything you do to it now is only making things worse.

Comment: As I stated in my first comment, and as others have pointed out, any speck of dust touching the platter's surface will render the drive entirely impossible to recover using any DIY technique. At this point, you must get it professionally recovered. Any more dust or running without the cover on could result in permanent data loss, even for a professional recoverer.